# How to pivot rows into a single column?

Tags: sql-server

I have some data in a table that I need to pivot. I have tried the replace function, but the query takes forever to run as there are thousands of rows to process on a regular basis. I need to put a CRLF at the end of each line in the second column so it displays in the application properly.

```
select obj_id, text from vDirections where obj_id='X01'
X01     EMERG MRKR ANT001: NEAREST I/S RYBURNE AV & ANNIVERSARY OUTER CIRCLE TRL    
X01     => GDA94 LAT:-137.873646 LON:155.175251 
X01     => TRAVEL NORTH-EAST 275M ON ANNIVERSARY TRAIL
```

Comment: please show the required result

Comment: X01  EMERG MRKR ANT001: NEAREST I/S RYBURNE AV & ANNIVERSARY OUTER CIRCLE TRL {CRLF} => GDA94 LAT:-137.873646 LON:155.175251 {CRLF} => TRAVEL NORTH-EAST 275M ON ANNIVERSARY TRAIL

Primary key is obj_id so for every different obj_id I want them all in a column

Comment: please update your question with the required result. It is much easier to read than in a comment

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on the cannonical Northwind example.

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + CompanyName
       FROM [Customers]
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [NAMES]
```

Result:

```
Alfreds Futterkiste,Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados,Antonio Moreno Taquería,Around the Horn,Berglunds snabbköp,Blauer See Delikatessen, etc., etc., etc.
```